# How do I use 'through' in a Django ManytoMany relationship?

Tags: django

I've read the docs, but there is one thing that isn't clear in using 'through' in a ManyToMany relationship.

Suppose I have a 'Convention' model and a 'Persona' model.

'Conventions' are collections of 'Persona'.

'Persona' is a representation of a type of person but does not contain a 'count'. A varying number of 'Persona' may join one or many 'Convention' -- and that's what I need to capture.

How do I say Convention A is made up of X number of Persona M, and Y number of Persona N? While a Persona represents a type of Person, it does not give me a count of the number of 'Persona M' attending a Convention? That's the extra data that I need to capture in the intermediate model.

That is, when setting up my models, should 'Convention' have a ManytoMany relationship to a table called 'ConventionPersonas' that has a count, a FK to Convention, and a FK to Groups?

-or-

Should I have a 'Convention' model that has a ManyToMany relationship with 'Persona' through 'ConventionPersona' -- and will that still allow a 'Persona' to be in many different 'Conventions'?

Models.py

```
class Convention(models.Model):
    personas = models.ManyToManyField(Persona through='ConventionPersona') #<-- use through here?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save_convention(self):
        '''
        Set timestamp and save object
        '''
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Persona(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

--proposed new model... use 'through'? --

```
class ConventionPersona(models.Model):
    '''
    A Persona should exist as a descriptor with zero
    count allowing a it to be used with 
    different weights, or counts, for different Conventions.
    '''
    conventionId = models.ForeignKey(Convention)
    personaId = models.ForeignKey(Persona)
    count = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: My first thought is that you just need `Persona` to have a foreign key to `Convention`.

Comment: Right -- but 'Persona' represents a type of person, not a count, and I need to be able to capture that count without tying a Persona to a single Convention.

Comment: Can you just use `.count()` in a query, then?

Comment: Helping out with this might go a bit easier if you go down a path to accomplish what you want, show us that work, tell us what you had hoped to accomplish and what you're doing is accomplishing instead.

Comment: Persona can't have a count because it represents a type of person. One Convention may have 10 people of Persona A attending, while another Convention might have 37 of Persona A.

Comment: Sure, but you can filter your `Persona` by something and attach `.count()` to it to get the count.

Comment: But what am I counting? If I assign a Persona to a Convention, I have a count of 1. I'll post the models.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you're saving you records.  If you add a new record for every Convention-Persona record then you could do something like this.

```
class ConventionPersona(models.Model):
    '''
    A Persona should exist as a descriptor with zero
    count allowing a it to be used with 
    different weights, or counts, for different Conventions.
    '''
    conventionId = models.ForeignKey(Convention)
    personaId = models.ForeignKey(Persona)
    count = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def myCount(self):
       p = ConventionPersona.objects.filter(personaId = self.id)
       return len(p)
```

Heavy on the processing though

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really provide the full structure of your models, but I'll assume the following:

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    persona_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Individual(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # In this example, an Individual can only have one Persona but 
    # a persona could be attached to many Individuals
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona)

class Convention(models.Model):
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Individual)
```

Because ManyToMany fields have an object manager, you can get the number of Personas by:

```
my_convention.people.filter(persona=persona_of_interest).count()
```

I'm not sure what your purpose would be of attaching a Persona directly to a Convention if you aren't including all members of that Persona; if there's another requirement here, feel free to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you are overthinking this or maybe I'm underthinking it, but I believe you will want to set up your `Persona` model this way, with a foreign key to `Convention`. This allows you to represent the fact that many persona can belong to a single convention

```
class Persona(models.Model):
    convention = models.ForeignKey(Convention)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Then to answer a question like the one you posed: How do I say Convention A is made up of X number of Persona M, you can do

```
convention_A = Convention.objects.get(name='A')
perona_m_count = Persona.objects.filter(name='M', convention=convention_A).count()
```

Comment: A Convention is made up of many Personas, and a Persona may be a percentage of many Conventions. Capturing the percentage is what's making this hard.

Comment: Well, the above captures the notion that a Convention can have many Personas. If you want a percentage of Personas to Conventions, you can count the number of Conventions and then just divide.

Comment: I think what I was missing was a Person - the granular element described by a Persona. A Persona describes a Person, a Person belongs to one, or many Conventions. Count the Persons of Persona A, B, C and so on...that make up the total Convention attendance. Simple math from there on out.

Comment: OK. Does this mean you can take it from here?

Comment: OK. Good. Hope I was able to help at least a little.